# Powershell script to add default content type to all libraries in a subsite

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, sub-site

I have a powershell script (thanks to this [link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/172c6a18-ce4a-43f1-b08a-c7bfbc597a9f/adding-content-types-to-libraires-though-powershell?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious)).

My environment: SP 2013.  Content type created on **root**, but want to use in only one **subsite**.

It looks like given below and set content type = true (if not) and add the content type.  But this is for the whole site collection.

I want it to run in the subsite called "DocCentre" only and add the content type in that subsite's libraries as **default** content type.  How can I accomplish that?

```
> #Get site object and specify name of the content type to look for in each library  $site = Get-SPSite http://<site>  $lookForCT = "Sales
> Document"
> 
> #Walk through each site in the site collection  $site | Get-SPWeb -Limit all | ForEach-Object {
> 
>      write-host "Checking site:"$_.Title
> 
>      #Go through each document library in the site
>      $_.Lists | where { $_.BaseTemplate -eq "DocumentLibrary" } | ForEach-Object { 
> 
>          write-host "Checking list:"$_.Title
>          $_.ContentTypesEnabled = $true
> 
>          #Check to see if the library contains the content type specified
>          #at the start of the script
>          if (($_.ContentTypes | where { $_.Name -eq $lookForCT }) -eq $null)
>          {
>              write-host "No content type exists with the name" $lookForCT "on list" $_.Title
>          }
>          else
>          {
>              #Add site content types to the list
>              $ctToAdd = $site.RootWeb.ContentTypes["HR Document"]
>              $ct = $_.ContentTypes.Add($ctToAdd)
>              write-host "Content type" $ct.Name "added to list" $_.Title
>              $ctToAdd = $site.RootWeb.ContentTypes["IT Document"]
>              $ct = $_.ContentTypes.Add($ctToAdd)
>              write-host "Content type" $ct.Name "added to list" $_.Title
>              $_.Update()
>          }
>      }  }  #Dispose of the site object  $site.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add custom content type from root site to document library in sub site and set the content type as default, the following PowerShell script for your reference.

```
Add-PSSnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell
$site = Get-SPWeb http://sp2013/sites/team/DocCentre
$lookForCT = "Sales Document"
#Go through each document library in the sub site
$site.Lists | where { $_.BaseTemplate -eq "DocumentLibrary" } | ForEach-Object { 
    write-host "Checking list:" $_.Title
    $_.ContentTypesEnabled = $true
    $_.Update()
    #Check to see if the library contains the content type specified
    #at the start of the script
    if (($_.ContentTypes | where { $_.Name -eq $lookForCT }) -eq $null)
    {
        write-host "No content type exists with the name" $lookForCT "on list" $_.Title
        $ctToAdd = $site.Site.RootWeb.ContentTypes[$lookForCT]
        $ct = $_.ContentTypes.Add($ctToAdd)
        write-host "Content type" $ct.Name "added to list" $_.Title
        $_.Update()
        $result=New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContentType]
        $result.Add($ct)
        $_.RootFolder.UniqueContentTypeOrder = $result
        $_.RootFolder.Update() 
    }   
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try following code snippet:

```
Add-PSSnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell

$site = Get-SPWeb http://sitename
$lookForCT = "Sales Document"
$site | ForEach-Object {
   write-host "Checking site:"$_.Title
   #Go through each document library in the site
   $_.Lists | where { $_.BaseTemplate -eq "DocumentLibrary" } | ForEach-Object { 

   write-host "Checking list:"$_.Title
   $_.ContentTypesEnabled = $true

   #Check to see if the library contains the content type specified
   #at the start of the script
   if (($_.ContentTypes | where { $_.Name -eq $lookForCT }) -eq $null)
   {
     write-host "No content type exists with the name" $lookForCT "on list" $_.Title
   }
   else
   {
     #Add site content types to the list
     $ctToAdd = $site.RootWeb.ContentTypes["HR Document"]
     $ct = $_.ContentTypes.Add($ctToAdd)
     write-host "Content type" $ct.Name "added to list" $_.Title
     $ctToAdd = $site.RootWeb.ContentTypes["IT Document"]
     $ct = $_.ContentTypes.Add($ctToAdd)
     write-host "Content type" $ct.Name "added to list" $_.Title
     $_.Update()
   }
}  }  #Dispose of the site object  $site.Dispose()
```

Comment: Perhaps I should have modified the script a bit.  I only want to add one content type: 'DCDocument' to the libraries in only one subsite.  So I want to check only http://sitenam/DocCentre/ (the subsite) for the content type and if not there, I want to add it and set as default.